Authorizing <video/> tag from html with JWT
The <video /> tag in HTML doesn't provide the possibility to change headers on requests. The only possibility I have found was to change the cross-origin prop, but due the security warnings and technicalities this did not work out for me.
I am looking for a way to change the Authorization header on the requests.
This is possible by requesting the video in JS with axios or standard fetch method, but the videos are stream-able and very long, thus I cannot wait for the whole video to be loaded first.
Is there another way in JS to solve this while keeping the video stream-able so I can skip through the videos without any lag.
I am actually working with react-player but as I can pass all props to the underlying video tag I figured a more general solution could be solved quicker.
The videos I am trying to stream are MP4 and preferably I would like to keep it that way.
Using the cross-origin prop
Looking at other Stackoverflow posts, there are many similar questions, but non that I have found provide a valid solution.

Use cookies? That way the browser will do that for you. Or a presigned url

@DanielA.White I have tried this, also with the cross-origin attribute as mentioned in my question (the video is accessed by using an API so not the same host as the Web application itself), didn't work out (at least not while using http). Using a signed url is only safe for one time usage (or a validity period.) This method is what I will use if I don't find a better solution. However I figured I couldn't be the only one who has faced this is issue. Thanks for your comment!
